# Don't use serialize for the user role Symfony

Tags: serialization, doctrine, symfony, silex

I have a project and a Symfony3 Silex 2 API that is based on the database created with SF3.
The problem arises because of the ROLE field in the database, in effect symfony3 stores in the database the user roles via serialize, flint or using a string.

Why Symfony serialize and flint right?
How to solve the problem because Silex does not manage the roles serialize?

Role field BDD:
Silex:

```
ROLE_MODO,ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
```

SF:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:9:"ROLE_MODO";i:1;s:16:"ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN";}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you use doctrine orm in silex and symfony?

Comment: I use doctrine with my project SF but not use with API Silex.
Juste that with silex : http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/providers/doctrine.html

Comment: Is the Symfony3 backend using FOSUserBundle?

Comment: In the sf3 the ORM User definition (Usually) have the field `<field name="roles" column="roles" type="array" />` that is handled with the deserialization of the array. So consider to use the same approach in the silex layer also.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure in SF3 platform, to map the `roles` field with `simple_array` DBAL type instead of `array`:

```
@ORM\Column(name="roles", type="simple_array")
```

The difference is that `array` type stores their values serialized and `simple_array` stores their values by using comma separated.

Answer (score 1):

**Symfony**
I think that `ROLE` field is mapped as `array` in doctrine orm, so serialization/unserialization is made automatically by doctrine orm.
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#array

**Silex**
You should unserialize roles manually. I don't know how you get user in silex..

```
class User implements Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface
{
    ...
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return unserialize($this['roles']);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work, because the method isGranted plant under symfony if it does not serialize and under Silex it's the same if not a single array that does not work.

I think we need to overload the method in Flint for the isGranted method unserialize take before the treatment? When do you think ?

Comment: unserialize roles in getRoles function in order to return array of roles, not serialized string

Comment: Can you explain how to override this class please?
For the getRoles method makes a unserialize in my project Silex?

Thank you !

Comment: I don't know how you code is organized. Add Silex User class code to question.

Comment: I just answered you in my post above (addition of code)

Comment: Someone would have an idea to load User I always hangs over ... Thanks!